# E-Mail connection strings / imported package

Tags: java

I have a number of different E-Mail providers.   I have a jar file for one of the providers.    I want to access the file from different modules each doing a specific task.

```
package mail;

import mailconnectpovidersslsend.MailConnectroviderSslSend;

public class ReadMail {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here
        MailConnectroviderSslSend SendSSL = new MailConnectroviderSslSend();
        SendSSL("mymail@domain.com","APassword");

        System.out.println("Hello");
    }
}
```

After defining `SendSS`L, I expected to call `SendSSL` with the required parameters, and the connection be made.   I am able to connect when `mailconnectprovidersslsend` is run on its own.

I get : error: `cannot find symbol`

The jar files exist in the libraries.

It is probably something very simple, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

`SendSSL` is a variable, so it should be written `sendSSL` (this is a stylistic point, but it will make your code easier to read).

You cannot invoke a variable as if it were a method in Java.

I'm guessing you either intended to call a constructor with those arguments:

```
MailConnectroviderSslSend sendSSL = new MailConnectroviderSslSend("mymail@domain.com","APassword");
```

or a method, but you forgot the method name:

```
MailConnectroviderSslSend sendSSL = new MailConnectroviderSslSend();
sendSSL.someMethodName("mymail@domain.com","APassword");
```

Comment: Hi Robin.  Thanks for the feedback.  Appreciate it.  I tried the

Comment: Hi Robin, I tried the sendSSL = new MailConnectroviderSslSend("mymail@domain.com","APassword");  and it gave me the 'error: not a statement' message.   Te intention to use  SendSSL as a reference throught the code when required.

Comment: I cannot see what is wrong. Please update your code in your question.